# showing the inserted value in the textview from the database

Tags: android

I want to read data from the sqlite database in android studio and show them using TextView in a different activity say activity 2. So in first activity i will fill details and click submit button and on clicking the activity 2 will open and will show all the details that i inserted in activity 1 in textview.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Google a bit. You will find a lot of tutorials which can help achieve this

Comment: Whats the problem????

Comment: Here is a link to android sqlite tutorial :) read it, you will solve the issue on your own :) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a example.

```
String dataOne;
for(int i=0; i < mListData.size();i++){
  dataOne = mListData.get(0).getName();
}
text_view.setText(dataOne);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the similar example what you are trying to achieve. below is the link
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/how-to-fetch-data-from-sqlite-database-in-android/